# is this a bug in the jquery autosuggest plugin

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

[i am using this plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) as an autocomplete suggestion box but one issue is that it allows me to enter the same tag more than once.  For example, if you

1. Use the example and type in "m" and choose Mick Jagger and then select that item (which adds it as a tag)
2. Then type in "m" again, **Mick Jagger still shows up on the list**.  If you select it from the dropdown, it will add it to the textbox again.
3. Then type in "m" again and Mick Jagger is no longer in the dropdown list.

This doesn't make sense to me why it would allow you to duplicate it once but not more than once.  For all further entries it does seem to eliminate existing items from the list so you can't have duplicate entries.

Is this just a bug in the jquery plugin?

Here is a picture of me having the ability to enter this same tag twice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to revert my previous assessment, there is no bug.
**It just dosen't work with mick jagger in the sample.**
Maybe there are 2 mick jaggers in the sample data or something like that.

If you try with any of the other names you will not get this issue.

Btw. in FF3 for me it works even with Mick Jagger, these seems to be something wrong with the sample code.

Comment: its NOT multiple mick jaggers in the data set as i can reproduce with my own data set (no duplicate)my new theory is that its actually a timing thing . . if you do it really slow you only get one mick jagger, but if you do it fast it shows up twice.  . any ideas

Comment: @ooo to be honest, the ui of the plugin might look good, but the code does not, if its an option ry looking at the jquery own, jquery ui auto complete plugin. Here is a post that describes how to basically get the same look as the one youre currently looking at: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/